# Link to python file in Jupyter notebook markup cell

Tags: jupyter-notebook

Suppose the following: I locally execute the `jupyter-notebook` server in my home directory.

I have the following files in `~/temp/jupyter_link`:

```
index.ipynb  python_file.py
```

In a markup cell in `index.ipynb` I want to create a link to `python_file.py`. This link should open `python_file.py` with the jupyter-notebook editor. I can do that with:

```
[python_file](https://localhost:8888/edit/temp/jupyter_link/python_file.py)
```

However, this link contains the absolute path of `python_file.py`. I want to use the relative path (with the base directory being the one from `index.ipynb`). I can create a link using the relative path with:

```
[python_file](python_file.py)
```

However, if I click this link I'm asked to download the file and it's not opened with the jupyter-notebook editor.

Is it possible to create a link that opens the python file with the jupyter-notebook editor but that uses a relative path? The pseudo-code I imagine would be something like:

```
[python_file](edit:python_file.py)
```

Inspired by @Ivan's answer I might add that

```
[python_file](/edit/temp/jupyter_link/python_file.py)
```

also opens the editor. That removes the host name from the link, but still does not give me a relative link.

Answer (score 1):

The following seems to work (nowadays?) in Jupyter 5.4.1 and Jupyterlab 0.32.1:

```
[python_file](./python_file.py)
```

Answer (score 0):

You already noted how this is solved in your question, but I kinda missed that

```
[python_file](/edit/temp/jupyter_link/python_file.py)
```

is actually the best answer. I figured it out after I found how to make the relative link and I was almost done writing this. So here is an explanation of how to do the relative and why the above link is actually better.

From the `index.ipynb` use the Jupyter file>open menu to navigate to the `python_file.py`. Look at it's address, in this case it should be something like

```
 https://localhost:8888/edit/temp/jupyter_link/python_file.py
```

Now look at your index file's address, should be something like:

```
 https://localhost:8888/notebooks/temp/jupyter_link/index.ipynb
```

To get to the `/edit` directory from the `/notebooks` you have to back out a few directories with `..`. The link should be something like

```
[python_file](../../edit/temp/jupyter_link/python_file.py)
```

However, you will always be backing up to the base of the Jupyter server directory to go from `/notebooks` into `/edit`, so just forget about counting `../` and just start with `/edit`.